# Installing KDE broke my Cinnamon installation

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde, cinnamon

I started my adventure with Linux Mint installing the MATE DE. Then I installed Cinnamon and switched to it. Recently I wanted to try KDE out. So I installed `mint-meta-kde`, `kde-full`, `amarok`, `kde-config-gtk-style` and Oxygen style for Gtk2 & 3.

I was playing around with KDE, set up the styling for Gtk apps in KDE. But eventually I decided to stick with Cinnamon.

I purge the installed packages with apt-get autoremove, besides purged any residual packages with `kde` in their names.

Unfortunately, now

- if I boot the system and select Cinnamon, then it takes about 20 seconds until the desktop is visible
- if I boot the system, log into MATE, log out, log into Cinnamon, it takes about 7 seconds until the Cinnamon desktop is visible

The user who used Cinnamon before installing KDE (and who never used KDE) has an almost instant login. So I created another user right now, and the new user has exactly the same problems as I.

Besides, the Linux Mint logo changed to the blue (KDE) one. The shell prompt was affected and now ends with `>`.

It is not related to any Cinnamon spice/desklet, since the new user was deprived of them.

What may be the cause? Can it be fixed without reinstalling?

My logs: 
`~/.xsession-errors`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11761939/ 
`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11761946/ 
`syslog` for the boot process: http://paste.linuxmint.com/view/4rpr 
bootchart: http://postimg.org/image/b4anarnfd/

The bootprocess for these logs was a direct boot to Cinnamon.

A side note: this was reported by me as a bug [to Cinnamon](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4333) and [KDE](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349331)