# Is installing KDE on my Fedora 34 installation going to ruin anything?

Tags: fedora, gnome, kde

This might seem like a stupid question, but when installing pantheon on my Linux Mint(Cinnamon) installation a few months back, and it exported some environment variables( I was a noob back then and thought I ruined my Mint). I also saw this [Forum](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211844/installing-kde-broke-my-cinnamon-installation) and this guy(or gal) had some minor-medium issues. I just want to test out KDE.

Comment: I'm using Fedora 34 - MATE. And installed KDE : `dnf groupinstall "KDE Plasma Workspaces"` because of missing Tk / wish support with a default Gnome or Mate install. .... No differences has been found with the MATE behavior. ( Except that 'wish' now works in Mate.)

Comment: Have you ever used Mate after getting KDE

Comment: Using Mate : Yes, I only use Mate. ... KDE was installed only to get `Tk` applications behave properly in Mate.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant have you used KDE after Mate installation?

Comment: KDE Plasma - X11, with "Plasma animations" disabled : KDE was used for various tasks today → Everything seems normal. ...... Gnome or MATE do usually not affect other window managers.